# React Native - Unable to pass body from onPress to action function in Context

Tags: javascript, react-native

Thanks in advance, everyone.  Total newbie to react native.  Using functional components only at this point.

In [AddGuestScreen.js](https://github.com/nyctoric/golfbudsmobile/blob/654c63de9e6371ecd217f6d2a5edef342aca4f55/src/screens/AddGuestScreen.js)  I am capturing this TextInput and submitting {guestA} to the action in [TeeTimeContext.js](https://github.com/nyctoric/golfbudsmobile/blob/654c63de9e6371ecd217f6d2a5edef342aca4f55/src/context/TeetimeContext.js)

```
  <View style={styles.boxContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.large}>Guest Name:</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        value={guestA}
        onChangeText={(text) => setGuestA(text)}
        autoCorrect={false}
      />
  </View>

  <View style={[styles.butttonContainer, styles.mainButton]}>
    <Button
      title='Save'
      color='white'
      onPress={ ({guestA}) => addGuestSave({guestA}) }
    />
  </View>
```

guestA is being passed as undefined from the onPress method and I don't understand why.

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The `onPress` event from the `Button` doesn't have the property `guestA`.

You can define a function for the button and pass in `guestA` inside `AddGuestScreen` before the return like so:

```
_handlePress = () => {
  addGuestSave(guestA);
};
```

And then pass the function to the `Button`

```
<Button onPress={_handlePress} ... />
```

Comment: The non-helper solution would be: `onPress={() => addGuestSave(guestA)}` Although you might need to wrap `guestA` in `{` `}` since OP seems to want to pass an object with the property `guestA`.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Need to add curly braces for state variable but with that one change it worked.